# Add object to array only if the object is not in already

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray

I want to add object to array only if the array already does not contain that object. 
How to do opposite of containsObject method in NSArray ?

Comment: Using the not operator? (which, I guess, is `!` as in all C-type languages)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use an [`NSMutableOrderedSet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSMutableOrderedSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSMutableOrderedSet), whose [`addObject:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSMutableOrderedSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009981-CH2-SW1) method does exactly what you want:

> Appends a given object to the mutable ordered set, if it is not already a member.

Comment: Exactly right. A set is an array plus uniquing, which is exactly what he's asking for.

Comment: @matt: An _ordered_ set is an array plus uniquing; sets normally do not preserve order.

Comment: Note that NSMutableOrderedSet was only introduced in iOS5, for earlier platforms you'll have to use an NSMutableSet (which is fine as long as you don't care about preserving the order you inserted objects in).

Answer (score 6):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
if (![myArray containsObject:objectToAdd]){
[myArray addObject:objectToAdd];
}
```

More detail here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html

Note that because the containsObject method queries every object in the array there are some performance considerations when using it on larger arrays.

Answer (score 0):

if your object is of `NSString`*  type you can do fast enumeration like this

```
BOOL found = NO;

for(NSString *object in YourArray)
{
 if([object isEqualtoString:@"My text"])
 {
 found = YES;
 }
}
if(!found)
{
//addObject
}
```

there are many isEqual methods in objective-c for different data types